# Is it possible to save animation as frame by frame to edit?

Tags: animation, video, frame-rate

I'm pretty sure this is not a duplicate question been look for this for a month now.

I'm planning to make animations with blender and heard of the grease pencil thing but I need to make 3d animations and edit them.

As in a basic frame rate even with 15fps a 10-20 minute animation would be 9000-18000 frames and to edit every single one would to save each and every frame individually. Is there a way to use the grease pencil with 3d animation or is there a way to actually save 18000 frames?

Somehow I managed a while ago to download a 4 hour video.(around 1.6gb)
Would that be the same as frame by frame or has it been compressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender does have the ability to render to individual frames (PNG format is popular) and this is the preferred workflow.

[image: output options]

I like to increase the compression to 100%, and if you aren't rendering frames with transparency, then use RGB instead of RGBA.  And uncheck the Overwrite box.  If you decide you need to throw away the previously rendered frames (because you updated the animation or whatever) you can delete them using your file explorer or bash.

As you have calculated this can result numerous images, which are usually each pretty large.

When you say you intend to "edit" the results of blender's rendering, you are being pretty vague, and depending upon the nature of the alterations you want to perform, your workflow can vary drastically.

Comment: Wow thanks! :D I have a couple of questions to this, the type of editing I plan is simple as in adding a mouth to the animation with out the 3d modeling to make the mouth 2d. But would importing 18,000 frames be a bit much? Or with 100% compression would I be able to still edit them? Sorry I'm new to animation and blender when it comes to this xD

Comment: The technique I would try for adding a 2D mouth to a 3D rendered character would be to render the 3D character, and then create a second blender project which uses the VSE to layer the mouth images over the 3D rendered character using image and movie strips.

Comment: By render do you mean load the animation to the vse? Cause the main problem I'm worrying about it trying to draw animation on compressed animation files, I'm not completely sure if I can just seethe frames in it or I'm I thinking of compression in the wrong way? Is it different than zip?

Comment: I would render the 3d character to a sequence of individual PNGs.  But blender's VSE supports both PNG sequences and encoded (compressed) video.  PNG compression is not lossy.  Most video encoders are lossy (but some have a lossless mode).  And when you use the VSE it is not exactly that you are "drawing on" the original video, but you are mixing together two or more videos which can achieve a "drawing on" effect and many other effects.

Comment: Thanks for all the help :D think I found the answer thx to you. I'm going to try 2 methods to test, the method you gave, and a method I seen on youtube where 2d grease pencil animations gonna try to render grease pencil in the png render images. If you want I could give you updates on both when I complete it.

Comment: After you have experimented with grease pencil, you could write a second answer to this question that outlines the technique and enumerates some advantages and difficulties so that people can learn from it (I have not really experimented with the grease pencil at all).  Having diverse answers on a question is sometimes a good thing.

Comment: This answer only covers configuring the output destination. To actually render, use the Render menu > Render Animation (and don't waste time looking for "the Animation button" that the Blender docs unhelpfully reference).